# How do you add a view to the end of a multi-line Text view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `Text` view that is dynamic, and can sometimes be a long name that spans 2 or 3 lines. How can I add a view immediately next the last word of a multi-line `Text` view?

[image]

How can I move `Age (23)` immediately to the right of "last-name" ?

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Text("First Middle hyphenated-long-last-name")
    Text("Age (\(age))")
        .font(.caption2)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a plus(+) sign between the Text views. This will concatenate the Text views while keeping each Text view's unique formatting.

```
var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Text("First Middle hyphenated-long-last-name") +
        Text(" Age (\(age))")
            .font(.caption2)
    }
}
```

Examples with different frame widths:

[image]

[image]

[image]

...and the HStack or other grouping is not needed when concatenating unless additional group formatting is needed.

Comment: I had no idea this was possible, thank you!

Comment: This answer was better than mine. I was not aware you could concatenate `Text` views.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t mind the age being the same size as the name, you can just put them in the same `Text` view:

```
HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    Text("First Middle hyphenated-long-last-name" + " Age (\(age))")
}
```