Text with special char does not scale
I noticed that in this SwiftUI Preview the US dollar sign does not scale proportional to the number next to it.
Initially I thought it was that the first Text did not scale but, as seen in the example, it's actually the Text with the fewer characters. Why does this happen and how does one fixes it?
#Preview {
    let view1 =
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("$")
        Text("999,999,999,999.99")
    }
    .lineLimit(1)
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)

    let view2 =
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("999,999,999,999.99")
        Text("$")
    }
    .lineLimit(1)
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)

    let view3 =
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("999,999,999,999.99")
        Text("%")
    }
    .lineLimit(1)
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)

    let view4 =
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        Text("12345")
        Text("67890")
    }
    .lineLimit(1)
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)


    let views = [
        view1.frame(width: 300),
        view1.frame(width: 100),
        view2.frame(width: 300),
        view2.frame(width: 100),
        view3.frame(width: 300),
        view3.frame(width: 100),
        view4.frame(width: 300),
        view4.frame(width: 50)
    ]

    return ForEach(views.indices, id:\.self) { index in
        views[index]
    }
}


Let's assume it is not possible to put everything in the same Text, which one alternative.

Try applying .scaledToFit() to each HStack:
let view1 =
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("$")
    Text("999,999,999,999.99")
}
.lineLimit(1)
.minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
.scaledToFit()

let view2 =
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("999,999,999,999.99")
    Text("$")
}
.lineLimit(1)
.minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
.scaledToFit()

let view3 =
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("999,999,999,999.99")
    Text("%")
}
.lineLimit(1)
.minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
.scaledToFit()

let view4 =
HStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("12345")
    Text("67890")
}
.lineLimit(1)
.minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
.scaledToFit()


The modifier .scaledToFit needs to be applied before the .frame modifier that constrains the width. This is why it needs to be applied to each HStack and cannot be applied to the items inside the ForEach.

why does that modifier fix it?

@fingia It means that scaling is performed on the contents of the container as a whole, instead of one text element being made smaller to fit in the space that is left by another. See also How to apply the same font size to multiple Texts within an HStack and size the HStack to fit its parent?

Concatenation(+) and Group
The Text views can be concatenated using the "+" operator to lay the text views out as a single string. When using a Group, the modifiers will affect all elements within the group. The modifiers don't affect the Group itself just its contents.
#Preview {
    VStack {
        let view1 =
        Group {
            Text("$") +
            Text("999,999,999,999.99")
        }
        .lineLimit(1)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
        
        let view2 =
        Group {
            Text("999,999,999,999.99") +
            Text("$")
        }
        .lineLimit(1)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
        
        let view3 =
        Group {
            Text("999,999,999,999.99") +
            Text("%")
        }
        .lineLimit(1)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
        
        let view4 =
        Group {
            Text("12345") +
            Text("67890")
        }
        .lineLimit(1)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
        
        let views = [
            view1.frame(width: 300),
            view1.frame(width: 100),
            view2.frame(width: 300),
            view2.frame(width: 100),
            view3.frame(width: 300),
            view3.frame(width: 100),
            view4.frame(width: 300),
            view4.frame(width: 50)
        ]
        
        return ForEach(views.indices, id:\.self) { index in
            views[index]
        }
    }
}



what if you have a font that is different for the "$" and the rest?

@fingia Modifiers can be applied to each Text separately. I have an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75497876/1816667
